# Receive action not getting all the properties sent from back end

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux, react-redux

From my backend, I'm sending an object that looks like this:

```
{
    userId: 1,
    firstName: 'Zack',
    lastName: 'Shapiro',
    finishedSetup: false,
    phone: undefined,
    organizationId: 5,
    email: 'testuser@example.com',
    admin: false,
    books: [array of books],
    authors: [array of authors],
    stores: [array of stores]
}
```

and yet in my action, `receiveUserSetup`, properties like `finishedSetup` aren't present

```
export function receiveUserSetup(user) {
    return { type: 'receiveUserSetup', user };
}
```

I can see them before I return from my server action but when I receive the data in my React app, some properties are missing. Any idea why?

Comment: Have you tried dumping user in a `CL` and seeing it the properties are being passed correctly? How does your reducer look?

Comment: CL = command line? At this point, my object hasn't hit the reducer, so it shouldn't matter how the reducer looks since the data isn't there

Comment: I printed the values in my command line for the user as well as the ones that are missing in my JS and they're there right before they return from the server...